# extract value with regular expression or parsing

Tags: python, regex

i'm trying to find a pattern in a huge string and get the value i need.

i'm not that familiar with regular expression, thus i'm not sure how to solve it.

example of the string:

```
href="https://www.johomojo.com/one?fref=pb&amp;hc_location=cons_tab">the value i want</a></div>
```

it will always start with:

```
location=cons_tab">
```

and ends with:

```
</a></div>
```

is there a good practice for solving this in regular expression or parsing?

Comment: You should use `BeautifulSoup` to parse this kind of stuff instead of `regex`

Comment: Sorry, it would end with what?

Comment: Where does the string come from? Does it comply with any markup language -- HTML, XML, etc?

Comment: In any event, using pyparsing would be a bad idea unless you're writing a completely new and custom parser, and if -- as your sample data makes it appear -- this is content a stock off-the-shelf parser could handle, you should be using that.

Comment: i edited the question.. it ends with </a></div>.
it is html.

Comment: add the actual html. it will be a lot easier extract using beautifulsoup

Comment: how are you getting the string?

Comment: i get the html source code from selenium library

Comment: Might be a lot easier if you can share the link you are scraping

Comment: What you want to extract from this string(HTML content)? Value of `href` of `a` tag or text content of `a` tag?

Comment: @VivekSable, I think `the value i want` is a clue, but considering the example is not valid html it will be hard to do either

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: yes, then OP can use `xpath` method of parser(e.g. `lxml`) to get target tag value.

Comment: The naive solution is to use a regular expression with a lookbehind and lookahead, but the PROPER solution is to use BeautifulSoup. I'll leave the BeautifulSoup solution to someone more-equipped to test it (I just had to wipe this machine so I don't even have an interpreter atm) but the regex looks like `re.search(r'(?<=location=cons_tab">).*?(?=</a></div>)')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
reobj = re.compile(r'<a\b[^>]href=".*?location=cons_tab.*?"[^>]*>(.*?)</a>', re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
match = reobj.search(text)
if match:
    result = match.group(1)
else:
    result = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `BeautifulSoup`:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('your_html')
>>> for x in soup.find_all('a'):
...     if x.get('href').endswith('location=cons_tab'):
...         print x.text
... 
the value i want
```

Using `regex`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("<a.*location=cons_tab.*>(.*)</a>",'your_html')
['the value i want']
```